# How to detect when user has run WP7 XNA Application again while deactivated?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I have a Windows Phone 7 game written with XNA 4.0 in C#.

It seems that the [Game.OnExiting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onexiting.aspx) method can be avoided if the user does the following:

1. Starts game through Tile in Windows Phone OS.
2. During gameplay, press the WINDOWS button to leave the game (resulting in a call to [Game.OnDeactivated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.ondeactivated.aspx%22Game.OnDeactivated%22) but not [Game.OnExiting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.onexiting.aspx)).
3. User starts the game again through the Tile in Windows Phone OS.

I have read much on the WP7 App Lifecycle, but haven't been able to find anything touching on this case where the user runs the same app twice in a row.

I have some logic that only makes sense to be called if the game is shutting down, and is also important that it isn't missed (such as in the case above). I cannot call it in `OnDeactivated` because it would cause a poor user experience.

Here is the code in question (found inside my implementation of the Game class):

```cs
protected override void OnExiting(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // This is what is getting missed!
    ForceSave();

    base.OnExiting(sender, args);
}

protected override void OnDeactivated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    base.OnDeactivated(sender, args);

    // I don't want to put ForceSave here because it will get called even if the user is not exiting the game.

    ...
}

protected override void OnActivated(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    base.OnActivated(sender, args);

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can handle that case.
I don't know what is your game about, but the easiest solution is to call `ForceSave` (I suppose it's a saving method) at the end of a level or before showing another menu, you can't save user's progress only before closing the application. Sometimes the game could crash with no reason and you have to prevent this.
In a nutshell, you have to revise your save logic.

Comment: The call to ForceSave populates the Leaderboard with the player's current score (if it is high enough). I do this during the normal flow (eg. at the end of a level) as well but want to handle the case where the game is exited mid-level. This makes sense if the user is exiting the game, but would be really weird if the user then returned to the session and saw their highscore in the leaderboard before they actually finished the game.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you want to update the player score if he hasn't completed the current level? You should have done this before its beginning.

Comment: It's just for a better user experience. Imagine my game is Tetris or Pac-Man. If the user quits before actually dying, it seems fair to save his score as it was when he quit, since there is no way for his score to have gone down if he stayed in the game. Hopefully that helps explain my motivation. If you have other ideas on how to solve this, I am very open! For instance, maybe I serialize the score to a temp field OnDeactived, and then OnActivated check if that field is currently storing anything, and if so, save it to the real highscore field. Hoping for general solution though.

Comment: I don't agree, a score should be saved only when the game ends (with his win, or a gameover in the game you named), not when the player quits the game. If he quits he doesn't deserve to save his score, imho.